# fernet key error "Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes"

Tags: python, byte, fernet

I keep getting this error but cant find any helpful information on it. i am not storing it in a file but instead storing it in the decryption code so that no one can see it once it is compiled (if there is a better way of storing the key let me know please).

here is the error

```
get_data = ast.literal_eval(Fernet(Key).decrypt((Message).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 38, in __init__
    "Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes."
ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.
```

here is my section of code

```
Key = b'pT8ZDjwCvnWkfPEYBm12q2p9srNkM-nWC6Ss9aAcMEw='
```

i made the code a bit easier to read

```
message_to_decrypt = (message_to_decrypt).encode('utf-8')
ast.literal_eval(Fernet(Key).decrypt(message_to_decrypt ).decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import base64

key = b'pT8ZDjwCvnWkfPEYBm12q2p9srNkM-nWC6Ss9aAcMEw='

key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(key)
```

If this does not work provide the sample code that give you the error